# Compare previous XML attribute with current in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this XML:

```
<note>
      <text style="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
      <text style="italic">consectetur adipisicing elit, </text>
      <text>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</text>
      <text style="bold">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</text>
      <text>ullamco</text>
</note>
```

Here's my problem:

I want to loop through the xml and compare the attributes with the previous attribute to see if they are the same. If they are the same I want to do nothing. If they are not the same I want to save the value of the attribute (italic, bold etc) to an ArrayList.

Here's my code:

```
List<String> styles = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Node> textNodesXML = new ArrayList<Node>();
textNodesXML = xpath.getNodes("/note/text");

for (Node n : textNodesXML)
{
   Node attribute = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("style");
   Node nextSibling = getTheNextSibling(n);
   Node siblingAttribute= nextSibling .getAttributes().getNamedItem("style");

   //Code is working up until here.

   if (attribut != null && siblingAttribute.getNodeValue() != attribute.getNodeName())
   {
       styles.add(attribute.getTextContent());
   }
}


public static Element getTheNextSibling(Node node)
   {
      Node sibling = node.getNextSibling();
      while (sibling != null)
      {
         if (sibling.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
         {
            return (Element) sibling;
         }
         sibling = sibling.getNextSibling();
      }
      return null;
   }
```

I want this to land in my ArrayList styles:

```
italic
bold
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Easier to use a `HashMap` for checking. Do you want to check only for attribute of a previous element or for all attributes that occurred before?

Comment: Only the previous attribute.
How can I use a HashMap?

Comment: What happens if you have 4 elements elements that alternate the same attribute? For example:  italic, nothing, italic, nothing? Your comparison would add 2 italics to `ArrayList`. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the desired behaviour.
I want to add every attribute as long as there are not two in a row.
Example:
italic, none, italic, none, bold, bold, none, bold
would add 2 italics and two bolds.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the current style value with the last one in the list:

Instead of

```
styles.add(attribute.getTextContent());
```

do

```
if (styles.isEmpty() || !styles.get(styles.size() - 1).equals(attribute.getTextContent())) {
    styles.add(attribute.getTextContent());
}
```